# Android Detail Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My app crashed and I get following error, if I try to open a DeatilFragement in my view:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'login' with
>   ID 2131558406 for field 'login' was not found. If this view is
>   optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
>   at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:92) at
>   butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(Utils.java:104) at
>   de.dev.myapp.ui.quote.ArticleDetailFragment_ViewBinding.(ArticleDetailFragment_ViewBinding.java:23)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) at
>   butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199) at
>   butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:172) at
>   de.dev.myapp.ui.base.BaseFragment.inflateAndBind(BaseFragment.java:29)
>   at
>   de.dev.myapp.ui.quote.ArticleDetailFragment.onCreateView(ArticleDetailFragment.java:69)

ArticleDetailFragment_ViewBinding refers to this line:

```
  public ArticleDetailFragment_ViewBinding(ArticleDetailFragment target, View source) {
    this.target = target;

    target.login = Utils.findRequiredViewAsType(source, R.id.login, "field 'login'", TextView.class);
```

BaseFragment refers to this line:

```
public View inflateAndBind(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, int layout) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view); // this line

    LogUtil.logD(TAG, ">>> view inflated");
    return view;
}
```

And ArticleDetailFragment refers to this line:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflateAndBind(inflater, container, R.layout.fragment_article_detail); // this line

    if (!((BaseActivity) getActivity()).providesActivityToolbar()) {
        // No Toolbar present. Set include_toolbar:
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setToolbar((Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }

    if (dummyItem != null) {
        loadBackdrop();
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(dummyItem.title);
        author.setText(dummyItem.author);
        quote.setText(dummyItem.content);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

And this is how I select each item to move to the details page

```
   @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        if (twoPaneMode) {
            // Show the quote detail information by replacing the DetailFragment via transaction.
            ArticleDetailFragment fragment = ArticleDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.article_detail_container, fragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Start the detail activity in single pane mode.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ArticleDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ArticleDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Required view 'login' with ID 2131558406 for field 'login' was not found.
    If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods)
```

That means that it is exceedingly likely that your `ArticleDetailFragment` includes these lines:

```
@BindView(R.id.login)
private View login;
```

The problem is that there is no view with the attribute `android:id="@+id/login"` inside your fragment's layout. Either add this view (or correct its id attribute), or mark your `View` as `@Nullable`.